# Getting latest state value with React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to use React Hook with functional component but ran into this case that requires getting the latest value, I think with class component you can rely on `this.state.foo` to be the latest value but not sure if that's possible with React Hook.

**Use case**

The UI has a toggle switch with two states - A and B, when user switches to A, we make an ajax call to get data for A and display in the UI, same for B.

**My code with useEffect**

```
function (props) {

    const [myState, setMyState] = useState('A')
    const [myText, setMyText] = useState()

    useEffect(()=>{
        ajaxCall(myState).then((data)=>{
            setMyText(data)   
        })
    }, [myState]) 

    return <div>{myText}</div>

}
```

This is usually working but not always, ajax call takes seconds to complete and user can toggle the switch pretty fast and we run into problem like below:

User switch to A, ajax call tries to get data for A.

Ajax call for A hasn't got back, user switch to B, new Ajax call is made and get data back very soon and update `myText` for B.

10 sec later ajax call for A finally returned and update the `myText` for A.

Now you see the problem - user selected B but UI is rendering `myText` for A.

**Solutions**

1. Once ajax call return, before setting `myText`, check the latest value of `myState`, if it has changed, then we don't update `myText`
2. Add a cleanup method to `useEffect` to abort the previous ajax call if it hasn't completed.

I don't know if solution 1 is possible with React Hook, so it seems the preferred way is solution 2?

Comment: When is `setMyState` called?

Comment: UI is a toggle switch, so user manually click on it toggle between A and B and that calls setMyState()

Comment: you can use axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) with allow to cancel a promise... there are a useEffect format for unmount, and it could be used to cancel the promise, if not done. If it was done, the cancel will has no effect.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo right, that's my solution no.2, I'm just curious if it's possible to get the latest `myState` in a callback with useEffect...

Comment: In this case, you can use React.memo to recover the last myState without the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a cleanup method that will not abort the ajax call, but rather just tell your `useEffect` hook that the value is no longer current, and then ignore `setText` if the return value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isCurrent = true;
  ajaxCall(myState).then(data => {
    if (isCurrent) {
      setText(data);
    }
  })
  return () => {
    isCurrent = false;
  }
}, [myState]);
```

Comment: wow! this is very interesting, I'll leave it here for some time to see if everyone thinks this is the best approach.

Comment: Very nice pattern. I never thought of that